# Connected Animation in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Class Icons.cs:

```
public class Icon
{
    public int IconID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }
    public string ImageCover { get; set; }
}
public class IconManager
{
    public static List<Icon> GetIcons()
    {
        var Icons = new List<Icon>();
        Icons.Add(new Icon { IconID = 1, Title = "Mr.Ha", Room = "611-Room", ImageCover = "Assets/Ha.jpg" });
        Icons.Add(new Icon { IconID = 2, Title = "Mr.Synh", Room = "611-Room", ImageCover = "Assets/Synh.jpg" });
        return Icons;
    }
}
```

Class MainPage:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Icons = IconManager.GetIcons();
    }

    private void ForegroundElement_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var icon = (Icon)e.ClickedItem;
        var tittle = icon.Title;
        ForegroundElement.PrepareConnectedAnimation("ca1", icon, "ConnectedElement");
        switch (tittle)
        {
            case "Mr.Ha":
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
                break;
        }
    }
    private async void ForegroundElement_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Icons != null)
        {

            ForegroundElement.ScrollIntoView(Icons, ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Default);
            ForegroundElement.UpdateLayout();
            ConnectedAnimation animation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation("ca2");
            if (animation != null)
            {
                await ForegroundElement.TryStartConnectedAnimationAsync(
                    animation, Icons, "ConnectedElement");
            }
        }
```

Class BlankPage1:

```
    public BlankPage1()
    {
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        ConnectedAnimation imageAnimation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation("ca1");
        if (imageAnimation != null)
        {
            imageAnimation.TryStart(TargetElement);
        }
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().PrepareToAnimate("ca2", TargetElement);
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
```

There something wrong with my Animation when I "Navigate Back" to the MainPage. The picture just stay still there then it's disappear, while the listview is done loaded !!My navigation from MainPage to BlankPage1 is fine though!!

Answer (score 0):

Your second connected animation is called `ca2`, but you are using `ca1` in the `MainPage`'s `ForegroundElement_Loaded` event handler. Because of this, the animation cannot be connected, which results in the behavior you are seeing.